# C++ Winsock unicode problem

Tags: c++, c, unicode, casting, winsock

I have just converted a program that uses winsock to unicode, and im running into a problem.

Here's my code, well part of it

```
TCHAR http_request[MAX_REQUEST_LEN];
TCHAR data[65536];
int nDataLen = 0;

/* Create http_request */

send(mySocket, (char*)http_request, lstrlen(http_request), 0)
nDataLen = recv(mySocket, (char*)data, 65536, 0);
```

I'm pretty sure casting `data` to a `char*` is causing the problem, thought i'm not completely sure.
There's no sendW or recvW so i'm wondering how i'm supposed to do this.

***EDIT:***
It's not crashing anymore thanks to Grim.
But now I've another problem, i've got this code but its returning `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`

```
TCHAR http_request[MAX_REQUEST_LEN];
char ansi_data[65536];
TCHAR data[65536];
int nDataLen = 0;

/* Create http_request */

send(mySocket, (char*)http_request, lstrlen(http_request) * sizeof(TCHAR), 0);

nDataLen = recv(mySocket, ansi_data, 65536, 0);

// Convert ansi_data to data, this is what causes the error
if (MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, ansi_data, nDataLen, data, 65536) == 0)
    ErrorExit(GetLastError());
```

Comment: You need to convert your http request as well.

Comment: When `MultiByteToWideChar()` fails, what is `GetLastError()` actually returning? Make sure that `nDataLen` is > 0, and your `data` buffer is large enough to hold the converted Unicode data. You should be calling `MultiByteToWideChar()` with a NULL destination buffer to determine the needed size, then allocate the buffer and call `MultiByteToWideChar()` again. You should also be looking at the HTTP reply's `Content-Type` header to determine the correct codepage to use for the conversion. `CP_ACP` is rarely the correct codepage to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you are mixing up different concepts.

To get the correct program you have to know what you are doing instead of mechanically replace "char" with "TCHAR" in your entire code.

Your internal string representation and the data you are sending over the network is totally different things.

How you represent text data internally is your choice (whether it is ANSI or UNICODE16 or UTF-8 or whatever) and any choice is OK when you implement it consistently.

But the data you are sending over the network is totally different thing - its format is defined by the protocol you are using. Of course `recv` function does not convert between character codings - it just sends data buffer over the network (as TCP connection data stream if you are using TCP socket). If you are sending HTTP request (as your variable name implies) then you have to use `char`s (not `TCHAR`s) because HTTP protocol uses ANSI characters.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably having a problem with your send statement. send() expects the 3rd parameter to be size in bytes, you are giving it characters. While this works fine for ANSI strings (sizeof(char) == 1) it won't work correctly for UNICODE.

sizeof(wchar_t) == 2

The correct code should look like this:

```
send(mySocket, (char*)http_request, lstrlen(http_request)*sizeof(http_request[0]), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, that keeps it from crashing. Now I think my problem is, I'm receiving the data in ANSI? And trying to process it as UNICODE. So I have to convert to UNICODE with something like `MultiByteToWideChar`. Right? Just wanna make sure I got this down.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data? Either way, MultiByteToWideChar is the way to convert from ansi to unicode.

Comment: The http protocol uses Ansi characters only, so there is no sense using `TCHAR` to begin with. As for receiving data, the encoding of the data is specified in HTTP's `Content-Type` header, so you cannot assume Ansi or Unicode. And the data may be compressed or otherwise transformed, so you have to look at the `Transfer-Encoding` header as well. Read RFC 2616 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't interchange char and TCHAR types, that would cause a problem.  You either need to declare data as an array of char, or change recv to use TCHAR.